# JDBC - Resultset is false

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I have the following problem.
I'm using JDBC and doing a query. But the qry doesn't work. If I let print out rs.next() it returns false.

The same qry works on the SQL-Developer itself, just not in JDBC. 
QRY:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select account_id, oper_type, new_value from action where account_id = 1");
        //ResultSet rsAccount = stmt.executeQuery("select account_id from accounts");
        System.out.println("Accounts Update");
        System.out.println(rs.next());
        if(rs.next() == true){
            System.out.println("Not null");
        }
```

Comment: why do you think it doesn't work? if `rs.next()` returns `false`, that means there are no more valid rows.

Comment: But it doesn't even print out the first result... That is the problem. I have 7 rows, and don't even get one row printed out. The same qry works in SQL-Developer

Comment: You are calling `next()` twice. So if there is only a single row, the second `next()` call (inside the if) will always return false. Additionally: you are not even using the data from the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I "solved" it. The problem was that my project tutor forgot to add commit; at the end of the sql file

Comment: Secondly, you are using `rs.next()` twice. Once in **print** statement and second in **if** statement. If you have only one record in select query, the if condition again fails. Comment the print statement for better result.